# Do you have to call .Save() when modifying a application setting that is bound to a control property?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, controls, application-settings

I am programming in .NET
I have an application setting of type string.
On my form I have a textbox. I bound the text property of the textbox to my application setting. If I type something in the textbox it changes the value that is held in the Application setting but the next time I start the program it goes back to the default value. Do I need to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` after the text is entered for the new value to be saved? Shouldn't it do this automatically? Is there a way I can make it do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be saved automatically, bind a handler to the TextChanged event and call Save() in it. It's just a double click and typing one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to call `Save` explicitly. The binding changes the setting value in memory, but doesn't save the file

Answer (score 2):

It is common practice to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` when close the application (for example, in `FormClosing` event).

Comment: This is my thought.  But, will this cause problems if there are multiple instances of the same application?